# Note in §8.2[dcl.ambig.res]/2 in N4140

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, disambiguation

In **§8.2[dcl.ambig.res]/2** we have the following note (emphases is mine):

> [ Note: A declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by a
>   nonfunction-style cast, by an = to indicate initialization or by
>   **removing** the redundant parentheses around the parameter name. —end note ]

Shouldn't it be **inserting** instead of **removing** above?

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S{ int i; S(int j) : i(j) {} };
float f = 1.0f;

S s(int(f)); // function declaration

int main()
{
    std::cout << s.i << '\n';
}
```

The code doesn't compile, as the compiler considers the declaration `S s(int(f));` as a function declaration. But if we do insert the parenthesis around the parameter name `f`, like `S s((int(f)));` the code compiles and prints 1.

Comment: It's trying to say that if you did intend to define a function, you shouldn't put parentheses around the parameter name.

Comment: I think it should say "removing". Taking the ambiguous definition `S s(int(f));`: inserting parentheses would give `S s(int((f)));` which is still ambiguous. However removing parentheses gives `S s(int f);` which is not ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with [Belloc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042389/belloc)'s argument. The Note could have been written with the following change (in bold) to give it a more precise meaning, an in this case the word `remove` doesn't make sense.

**An object** declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by a nonfunction-style cast, by an = to indicate initialization or by **<s>removing</s> inserting** the redundant parentheses around the parameter name. —end note

Comment: This would be incorrect though. Inserting redundant parentheses on an ambiguous declaration still results in an ambiguous declaration. (which declares a function).

Comment: Also, an ambiguous declaration is a function declaration, so "an object declaration" would exclude ambiguous declarations. I guess you mean "An ambiguous declaration which is intended to declare an object can be explicitly disambiguated by..."

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Simple's comment, it is telling you that the parentheses around the parameter name is redundant. This is reinforced by [defect report 340:  Unclear wording in disambiguation section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#340)  which was closed as Not A Defect and gives the following example:

```
  struct Point
  {
    Point(int){}
  };
  struct Lattice 
  {
    Lattice(Point, Point, int){}
  };
  int main(void)
  {
    int a, b;
    Lattice latt(Point(a), Point(b), 3);   /* Line X */
  }
```

and says:

> The declaration of latt declares a function with a return value of the
>   type Lattice and taking three arguments. The type of **the first two
>   arguments is Point and each of these arguments is followed by a
>   parameter name in redundant parentheses.** The type of the third
>   argument can not be determined, because it is a literal. This will
>   result in a syntax error.

Comment: The text you quoted just seems wrong to me. (It was written by the submitter of this rejected proposal).  `Lattice latt(Point(a), Point(b), 3);` cannot be a function declaration because of the `3`, therefore it is an object declaration.   Current compilers accept this code.